# Problem Sub Path Ingress Controller for Backend Service

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress

I have problem setting path ingress controller for backend service. For example i want setup :

1. frontend app with angular (Path :/)
2. backend service with NodeJs (Path :/webservice).

**NodeJS : Index.js**

```
const express = require('express')
const app = express()
const port = 4000

app.get('/', (req, res) => res.send('Welcome to myApp!'))

app.use('/data/office', require('./roffice'));
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Example app listening on port ${port}!`))
```

**Another Route:roffice.js**

```
var express = require('express')
var router = express.Router()

router.get('/getOffice', async function (req, res) {
   res.send('Get Data Office')
}); 

module.exports = router
```

**Deployment.yaml**

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: ws-stack
spec:
  selector:
   matchLabels:
     run: ws-stack
  replicas: 2
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
      run: ws-stack
  spec:
     containers:
     - name: ws-stack
       image: wsstack/node/img
       imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
       ports:
         - containerPort: 4000
```

**Service.yaml**

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: service-wsstack
   labels:
    run: service-wsstack
  spec:
   type: NodePort
   ports:
   - port: 80
     protocol: TCP
     nodePort: 30009
     targetPort: 4000
   selector:
     run: ws-stack
```

**ingress.yaml**

```
 apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
 kind: Ingress
 metadata:
   name: stack-ingress
   annotations:
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
  spec:
   rules:
    - host: hello-world.info
    - http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: service-ngstack --> frondend
            servicePort: 80
        - path: /webservice
          backend:
            serviceName: service-wsstack --> backend
            servicePort: 80
```

i setup deployment, service and ingress successfully. but when i called with curl

```
curl http://<minikubeip>/webservice  --> Welcome to myApp! => Correct
curl http://<minikubeip>/webservice/data/office/getOffice --> Welcome to myApp! => Not correct
```

if i called another route, the result is the same 'Welcome to myApp'. But if i used Nodeport

```
curl http://<minikubeip>:30009/data/office/getOffice => 'Get Data Office', working properly.
```

What is the problem? any solution? Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## TL;DR

- `nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2`
- `path: /webservice($|/)(.*)`

## Explanation

The problem is from that line in your ingress:

`nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /`

You're telling nginx to rewrite your url to `/` whatever it matched.

- `/webservice` => `/`
- `/webservice/data/office/getOffice` => `/`

To do what you're trying to do **use regex**, here is a simple example:

```
 apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
 kind: Ingress
 metadata:
   name: stack-ingress
   annotations:
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
     nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
  spec:
   rules:
    - host: hello-world.info
    - http:
        paths:
        - path: /
          backend:
            serviceName: service-ngstack --> frondend
            servicePort: 80
        - path: /webservice($|/)(.*)
          backend:
            serviceName: service-wsstack --> backend
            servicePort: 80
```

This way you're asking nginx to rewrite your url with the second matching group.
Finally it gives you:

- `/webservice` => `/`
- `/webservice/data/office/getOffice` => `/data/office/getOffice`

Comment: i am sorry @Noe..frontend service-ngstack cannot access anymore, backend working properly.. any solution again for path frontend?

Comment: The frontend should work at '/'. Does it works before ? The thing is taht the url of your frontend will always be '/' (in this config). So i suggest you to write your own regex to match the url and have a logic second group. Or if you want a quick fix you can do the same thing as the web service for the path

Comment: ow i am sorry, that's working.. my bad..thanks @Noe. Once question again, how to redirect to path : / if user write address not correctly, example : /foo, /bar. thanks

Comment: You need to make a regex that match everything except /webservice/* for your web app client and make sure that you only have one group so the URL will be rewrite /. You can find great regex editor online